# Setting chmod value in Ubuntu for all newly created files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmd, file-permissions, umask

How can I set 777 to all newly created files in some directory? I have tried looking on google, but it's really confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `umask` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work

If you want to change the umask value for some specific folders only, have a look there :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder
https://superuser.com/questions/612771/how-to-set-umask-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolder